# how to open Different Activity in one Activity like(Activity and in middle Show Tab layout)

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

i want to display two Activity  In one Activity ....one  Show  on top and second On Middle Show Tabs(about,gallery feeds)
both have to show On same Screen 
i am using actionbarSherlock Library

here is My Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    <RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="63dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/loader" />

</RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#00ffffff" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_frm"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img_frame" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_frm" >
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout1" >
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_frm"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout1" >
            </RelativeLayout>



        </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:background="#00ffffff" >




<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userfullname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="UsFn"
    android:textColor="#DF0B0B"
    android:textSize="30dip" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/userfullname"
    android:layout_marginTop="118dp"
    android:text="Log Out" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_green"
    android:text="Edit " />
```

i want to show tab in this Layout 
please help me i am really confuse and very new on android 
thanks for help

Comment: Try using more specific language for your question: "How to *Nest* an activity inside an activity"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [Google Search](http://goo.gl/Ga4M4U) would have found you a solution. Fragments are basically two layouts that can be used in a lot of different ways.

Comment: Sir i am very new on Android Can U Tell me How To Do what i want

Comment: Read about Fragments through the link in my answer. It's great that your new but we don't write code for you. If you Google "Fragments" or "Fragment Examples", you will find a lot of different implementations for what your trying to do. If your going to be an Android developer, Google Search has to be your best friend. Don't be discouraged ;) We all asked a question like this in our early stages of development. Again, you just have to use Google a lot.